# How to display associated model's attribute in Active Admin index with belongs_to/has_many relationship (Rails 3.2/Active Admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm building a daily deal Rails app to learn RoR.

I am facing a problem for the past few hours : i can't get a model's attribute of an other associated model on active admin. Let me show you exactly the problem :

I have two models: Brand (i.e the brand of the deal) and Deal. A deal belongs to a Brand but a Brand can have many Deals.

models/deal.rb is like this:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
```

and we have models/brand.rb:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :deals

  attr_accessible :name
```

And i did the t.belongs_to in my migrations so this is ok.

In Active Admin's Deals' create form , i type, as admin, which brand the deal is associated with:

admin/game.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Deal do
# -- Form -----------------------------------------------------------
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Brand (i.e. client)" do
      f.input :brand_id, :label => "Select a brand:", :as => :select, :collection => Brand.all
    end
```

it works great, and i can create Deals with a certain brand.
but **I CAN'T manage to display the NAME of the Brand in my list of Deals**:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Deal do
index do   
selectable_column   
# id_column 
column :title
column :deal_amount
column :brand do |deal|
  link_to deal.brand.name
end
```

...doesn't work.

How can I do that ?

I tried everything but **i basically don't know how to fetch the name of a Brand given it matches the brand_id in the Deal's table**.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
show do |f|
  panel "Subject" do
    attributes_table_for f, :name, :description, :is_visible
  end

  panel "Pages in List View" do
    table_for(f.pages) do |page|
      column :name
      column :permalink
      column :is_visible
    end
  end

  panel "Pages in View " do
    div_for(f.pages) do |page|
      panel page.name do
        attributes_table_for page, :name, :description, :is_visible
      end
    end
  end

end

end
```

You can do nested relations in same style as parent model

Answer (score 3):

A couple things seem missing:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brands, foreign_key: :brand_id, class_name: 'Brand'
end
```

This is assuming that you mean `partner` to be a `Brand` and your schema uses `brand_id` for that relationship.

In your form, you can simply use:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Brand (i.e. client)" do
    f.input :partner, label: 'Select a brand:'
  end
end
```

Your `link_to` call won't actually link to a url the way you have it.

```
column :brand do |deal|
  link_to deal.partner.name, admin_brand_path(deal.partner)
  # or simpler
  auto_link deal.partner
end
```

I would highly recommend trying to be consistent in your naming, as it will make things a lot less confusing and will require less code to make things work. i.e.

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
end

f.input :brand, label: 'Select a brand:'

auto_link deal.brand
```

And your DB column can still be named `brand_id`.

Comment: i'll try some of that but it was my mistake when i copied the code on SO: there is only 2 models Brands and Deal (so the firstis:  class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand) and not belongs_to:partner; i hope your explanations with auto_link will help me. I'll try tonight. thanks