# Can't display in Active Admin index attribute of associated model (belongs_to/has_many) - Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm building a daily deal Rails app to learn RoR.

I am facing a problem for the past few hours : i can't get a model's attribute of an other associated model on active admin. Let me show you exactly the problem :

I have two models: Brand (i.e the brand of the deal) and Deal. A deal belongs to a Brand but a Brand can have many Deals.

models/deal.rb is like this:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
```

and we have models/brand.rb:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :deals

attr_accessible :name
```

And i did the t.belongs_to in my migrations so this is ok.

In Active Admin's Deals' create form , i type, as admin, which brand the deal is associated with:

admin/deal.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Deal do
# -- Form -----------------------------------------------------------
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Brand (i.e. client)" do
      f.input :brand_id, :label => "Select a brand:", :as => :select, :collection => Brand.all
    end
```

it works great, and i can create Deals with a certain brand. but I CAN'T manage to display the NAME of the Brand in my list of Deals iun Active Admin'x index :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Deal do
index do   
  selectable_column   
  # id_column 
  column :title
  column :deal_amount
  column :brand do |deal|
    link_to deal.brand.name, admin_brand_path(deal.brand)
  end
```

...doesn't work.

How can I do that ?

I tried everything but i basically don't know how to fetch the name of a Brand given it matches the brand_id in the Deal's table.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**
the error i'm getting is it doesn't understand function .name: unknown method 'name'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display associated model's attribute in Active Admin index with belongs\_to/has\_many relationship (Rails 3.2/Active Admin)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307302/how-to-display-associated-models-attribute-in-active-admin-index-with-belongs-t)

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Are you seeing an exception? Or is nothing showing up there?

Comment: note if i use auto_link it works though...strange but i don't want to use it as it's quite old fahsioned rails i think

Comment: @JoshKovach i have updated question to put the error i get

Comment: Can you paste the exact printout of the error you are getting? What happens if you put `link_to deal.brand.name, admin_brand_path(deal.brand) unless deal.brand.nil?`?

Comment: @JoshKovach you're a magician. i'ma newbie and i indeed di'nt provide for the case of nils...that was the problem ! thanks a lot!!

Comment: this was the error i was getting undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass. now i understand it means nil.name could not make sense as sometimes game.partner = nil

Comment: Glad you got it! I realized that I missed this case in a few spots of my own code :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the case of `deal.brand` being `nil`.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Deal do
  index do   
    selectable_column   
    # id_column 
    column :title
    column :deal_amount
    column :brand do |deal|
      if deal.brand.present?
        link_to deal.brand.name, admin_brand_path(deal.brand)
      else
        status_tag('Empty')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `:brand` column looks correct to me.  If you find a `deal` in the console what do you get if do `deal.brand` and `deal.brand.name`?

Comment: i will try on the console tonight