# ActiveAdmin Index Associated Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to change the default text display in ActiveAdmin from the id to different, multiple attributes of an associated model object. (e.g. first name, last name).  How do I do this?

```
index do
    selectable_column
    column :artist
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so little documentation on this - here are two spots with answers to HABTM relations and index with ActiveAdmin:
http://eileencodes.com/posts/has-many-relationships-in-activeadmin/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19336576/5551783

Here's the concept:

```
    column :artist do |m|
        if m.artist.present?
            "#{m.artist.first_name} #{m.artist.last_name}"
        else
            status_tag('Empty')
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

One more Simple Solution :

```
column :artist do |model|
  auto_link "#{model.artist.first_name} #{model.artist.last_name}"
end
```